# How to post domain events with aggregate root Id before the root is persited?

Tags: domain-driven-design, persistence

This seems pretty newby question but I still can't find a answer I'm ok with.

I'm doing a microservice and decided to have a Message as an aggregate root. This Message represents a kind of announcement and incapsulates distribution rules.

From the other side I have a MessageHistory agg root to track creates\updates which in future go to external search system. So MessageHistory has MessageId and referenes Message.

In create Message command handler

- I call Message.ctor and add a MessageCreatedEvent to an events
  collection inside Message. At this point I don't have Message.Id (since SQL identity and
  no inserts yet).
- I do call Repository.Save and get Message.Id from DB via EF Core. Then dispatch domain events. But the thing is that event handlers cannnot get Message.Id to store in
  MessageHistory since event was added with Message.Id = 0.

So I see few options here:

1. I both add and dispatch events in command handler rather then create in Aggregate Root. Do it right after MessageRepository.Save when I have Id returned from RDBMS. But this seems to break the rule that Agg Root should own it's events. (*This is what I took for now*)
2. I should include MessageHistory in Message aggregate root and persist it in the same repo so I don't even need that MessageCreatedEvent. The only thing I worry is that I may have too much history records that may hurt performance when loading Message from DB for some operations over it. More on this that MessageHistory is only necessary for specific indexing process it's related with and Message can live without that history.
3. Rather that using Domain Events, switch to idea of Integration Event (but still handeled in the same process\codebase). This keeps coding similar to point 1 but just have another ideas underneath and domain events ownership doesn't violated.

Having GUIDs as ID is not an option since I cannot generate IDs other that SQL Identity from RDBMS.

Comment: You might want to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742826/how-do-i-know-the-id-before-saving-an-object-in-jpa). The gist is, instead of using an auto increment sequence for a table, to use a custom sequence, and to retrieve a "next value" when you create a new entity instance.

Comment: Thanks @StefanRendevski but this is unforunatelly a limitation I have to deal with due to a policy that I cannot jump over.